# Is there an alternative to the fortran binary file opening option "RECORDTYPE=stream"?

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran program where I have to open a binary output file. normally one specifies.

```
RECL=num
```

However for my particular case, a file opened with that option does not work. What works is

```
RECORDTYPE=stream
```

The gfortran which i normally does not accept the second option. With the RECL option, the program works, but the data is unusable. The Intel compiler does. Intel no longer gives a free compiler and I lost the free Intel compiler I had.

I would appreciate any suggestion to write a stream with gfortran, or if someone can backup their compiler folder, put it on google drive and give me the link (hoping this is not an abuse).
I work on Ubuntu 18.04.

I paste below, a sample program I use and the data to be written to binary.

```
     Program stndat
 implicit none

 integer                     :: iflag=0,itime=0
 integer                     :: nlev,ihrold,nflag,icount
 integer                     :: ihr   !,iwx,delta,cld,vis
 integer,dimension(1:3)      :: today,now

 Real                        :: lat,lon,iu,iv,itemp,idp,ipress

 CHARACTER(len=3)            :: stnid
 character(len=8)            :: date
 character(len=10)           :: time
 character(len=5)            :: zone
 character(len=8)            :: year,inst*10,hour*2
!
 integer,dimension(1:8)      :: values

 ! using keyword arguments
 call date_and_time(date,time,zone,values)
!
 open(1,file='tmp.txt')
 write(1,'(1x,a8,2x,a10)') date,time
     Program stndat
 implicit none

 integer                     :: iflag=0,itime=0
 integer                     :: nlev,ihrold,nflag,icount
 integer                     :: ihr   !,iwx,delta,cld,vis
 integer,dimension(1:3)      :: today,now

 Real                        :: lat,lon,iu,iv,itemp,idp,ipress

 CHARACTER(len=3)            :: stnid
 character(len=8)            :: date
 character(len=10)           :: time
 character(len=5)            :: zone
 character(len=8)            :: year,inst*10,hour*2
!
 integer,dimension(1:8)      :: values

 ! using keyword arguments
 call date_and_time(date,time,zone,values)
!
 open(1,file='tmp.txt')
 write(1,'(1x,a8,2x,a10)') date,time
 rewind(1)
 read(1,'(1x,a8,2x,a10)') year,inst
 close(1,status='delete')

 iflag=0
 itime=0
 icount=1

 hour = time(:2)
 hour = '09'
!    Open up I/O Files
Open(unit=11,file='../../Output/synop4grads.txt',status='old')
Open(unit=12,file='../../Output/Obs_out.bin',form='unformatted',recordtype='stream',status='unknown')
10   continue
 !   Read in the line of code


 read(11,'(1x,a3,2x,f5.2,2x,f6.2,2x,i2,8(2x,f5.1))',END=40) stnid,lon,lat,ihr,iu,iv,itemp,idp,ipress
   IF (iflag.EQ.0) THEN
   iflag=1
   ihrold=ihr
ENDIF
 !

     !       Check to see if this is an old time group. If so, write a terminator
         IF (ihrold.NE.ihr) THEN
            nlev=0
            write(12)stnid,lat,lon,ihr,nlev,nflag
         ENDIF

     !       Now make ihrold equal to the current ihr

         ihrold=ihr
    !
 !       Now we can go ahead and write the report
 !       First, define some variables to be used in the header

     itime=0.
     nlev=1
     nflag=1
         write(12) stnid,lat,lon,ihr,nlev,nflag
 !
 !       read in the following: itemp,idp,ipress,iu,iv,iwx,ic,icl
         write(12) iu,iv,itemp,idp,ipress
 !       When its done writing one report, instruct the program
 !       to read-in the next line
         go to 10
 !
 !       When there are no more lines to read-in, the program
 !       goes to 40
  40      continue
         nlev=0
 !
         write(12)stnid,lat,lon,ihr,nlev,nflag
      close(11)
      close(12)
    end
```

And the data

```
   403  29.08   -9.80  01   -0.5   -3.0   24.0   16.5  496.0
   441  24.43  -11.75  01  -99.0  -99.0   18.5   16.8  533.0
   461  28.85  -11.10  01   -1.4   -9.9   26.0   17.7  485.0
   475  31.12  -10.21  01   -1.0   -9.9   24.4   14.0  509.0
   476  31.25  -10.10  01   -0.7   -6.0   24.0   14.5  -99.0
   477  31.43  -11.90  01   -1.7  -49.0   -9.9    0.0  500.0
```

Comment: Does this: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Stream+Input+Output help?

Comment: This is interesting and thanks very much. I will give feedback when I try it.

Comment: Once more thanks very much @Roadowl the link you gave me solves it all. I no longer have any need for the other compiler I was crying for. GNU fortran suffices and does the job. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Glad it helped and the way  it did!